# WS02: error No artifacts found to be deployed in this server. Ignoring Carbon Application

Tags: esb, wso2, wso2-esb

Following process outlined here to create a axis service from a pojo:
Webinar: Building Applications with Carbon Studio for On-Premise and the Cloud.
I create the axis services as described in the webinar.
I did a mvn package sucessfully. 
I start the WS02 ESB in eclipse sucessfully.

But when I deploy my app to the WS02 ESB, I see the following in the console:

INFO - ApplicationManager Deploying Carbon Application : MyCarbonApp-1.0.0.car...
WARN - ApplicationManager No artifacts found to be deployed in this server. Ignoring

Carbon Application : MyCarbonApp-1.0.0.car
and the service does not appear on the ESB console's web services list.

When I look at the file called MyAxisService.service I see the following:

```
    #Contains the information about the axis2 service generation information from the eclipse workspace
#Fri May 25 15:53:09 NZST 2012
Class-name=com.unisys.comms.esbselection.MyAxisService
Type=FROM_CLASS
Service-name=MyAxisService
Projects=MyCarbonApp
```

What does this warning mean?
What can I do to further investigate the cause? 
Is there some obvious step I've missed when creating the app?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Please follow these steps to solve this issue.

1. Go to carbon.xml file locate in ....\wso2esb-4.9.0\repository\conf
2. Add new server role to  xml elemet
    
       EnterpriseServiceBus
       ApplicationServer
3. Restart the server

Comment: Adding to the answer, we can add any custom Server Role as     <ServerRoles>
        <Role>EnterpriseServiceBus</Role>
        <Role>esb_app</Role>
    </ServerRoles>

 in carbon.xml and have the same in car files artifact.xml <dependency artifact="HelloProxy" version="1.0.0-SNAPSHOT" include="true" serverRole="esb_app"/>

Answer (score 1):

This error means the Server Roles of the C-App Artifacts found in your Carbon Application Archive (CAR), does not match the Server Role of the ESB.

Reason is, Axis2 Web Services are by default has the Server Role of "ApplicationServer". Hence if you deploy it on the WSO2 AS, it will deploy without any problem. But in this case, you have tried to Deploy it the WSO2 ESB. Since the WSO2 ESB has the Server Role "EnterpriseServiceBus" and your Axis2 web service has the Server Role "ApplicationServer", they do not match each other. Result is the C-App deployer will ignore the C-App.

To solve this, you need to change the Server Role of your Axis2 Web Service. In order to do that, follow the steps below.

1. Go the C-App project you created and browse to the Axis2 Service Artifact folder in the "Artifacts" folder of the C-App.
2. Inside this Axis2 Service Project, you will see a file called "Artifact.xml". Open this file by double clicking on the file.
3. Once you double click on the file, file will be opened in the Artifact editor. Scroll the Editor down a bit.
4. There you will see a Drop Down next to a Label called "Server Role".
5. Select "EnterpriseServiceBus" option from the Drop down list and click on "Save All" button on the Eclipse Tool bar.
6. Go to the Servers view in Carbon Studio and click on the expand icon infront of the Carbon Server (WSO2 ESB in this case)
7. Once you expand the Server, you will be able to see the Server Module (C-App project) you deployed in the ESB.
8. Right Click on the C-App module under the ESB Server and Select "Redeploy".

Now you will see that Carbon Studio redeploy the C-App project and if you followed all the steps above correctly, your Axis2 Web Service will be deployed in the ESB.

Hope this helps!!

Thanks.

/Harshana